# How do I avoid getting NullPointerException in my Matrix sum?

Tags: java, matrix, nullpointerexception

I want to check if the sum of each row in any matrix is equal. How should I rewrite this to avoid NPE?

I can make it work for "normal" matrices like `int[][] a = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}`, but I want it to work even when testing with null and empty matrices.

```
public static boolean allRowSumsEqual(int[][] m) {
  boolean a = false;
  int x = 0;
  int total = rowSum(m[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
      x += m[i][j];
    }
    if (x != total) {
      a = false;
      break;
    } else {
      x = 0;
      a = true;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

public static int rowSum(int[] v) {
  int vSum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    vSum += v[i];
  }
  return vSum;
}
```

Comment: What do you think of using an `if` statement to check if the matrix is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a result or an exception if you want to check for "null" parameter. You can return `true` if null is valid or `false` otherwise.

```
if(m == null) return true;
```

Empty or one lined matrices can return `true` all the time and does not require any calculation:

```
if(m.length < 2) return true;
```

The line test is more simple, I think:

```
// expect a positiv result
boolean result = true;
// calculate first line
int firstLine = rowSum(m[0]);

// loop remaining lines
for (int i = 1 ; i < m.length ; i++){
    // compare first line with current line
    if (firstLine != rowSum(m[i]))
    {
       // not equal -> change result 
       result = false;
       // break loop
       break;
    }   
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, this does work for most matrices.  There are a few places I might check for null, see modified code below:

```
public static boolean allRowSumsEqual(int[][] m){
    if(m == null) return true;
    if(m.length == 0) return true;

    boolean a = false;
    int x = 0;
    int total = rowSum(m[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < m.length; i++){
        // You can use your own function instead of the inner for loop
        x = rowSum(m[i]);
        if (x != total) {
           a = false;
           break;
        } else {
           x = 0; 
           a = true;
        }   
    }
    return a;
}

public static int rowSum(int[] v){
    int vSum = 0;

    // Assume a null row has sum 0
    if(v == null) return 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < v.length ; i++){
        vSum += v[i];
    }   
    return vSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Snippet {
    public static boolean allRowSumsEqual(int[][] m) {
        if (null == m || 0 == m.length)
            return true;
        boolean a = false;
        int x = 0;
        int total = 0;
        if (null != m[0])
            total = rowSum(m[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < m.length; i++) {
            if (null != m[i]) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                    x += m[i][j];
                }
            } else
                x = 0;
            if (x != total) {
                a = false;
                break;
            } else {
                x = 0;
                a = true;
            }

        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int rowSum(int[] v) {
        int vSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            vSum += v[i];
        }
        return vSum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 2, 1 }, null };
        System.out.println(allRowSumsEqual(a));
        int[][] b = { null, null, null };
        System.out.println(allRowSumsEqual(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this solution:

```
public static boolean allRowSumsEqual(int[][] m) {

    if(m == null) { return false; }

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

        int temp = 0;

        if(m[i] == null) { continue; }

        for(int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            temp += m[i][j];
        }

        if(i == 0) {  //is the first row
            sum = temp;
        }
        else if(sum != temp) { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```